# How to compile SWIG generated C# files into a .NET DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, swig

In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268/what-are-the-best-practices-when-using-swig-with-c/1070469#1070469), Marc Bernier mentioned "SWIG also generated a bunch of C# files which I compiled into a .NET DLL".

I generated the C# files for my class too. But I really can not figure out how to build that into a .Net Dll. I'm totally noob to .Net and DLL.

Seems I '@' is not working here. @MarcBernier. Or anyone knows how can I contact Marc?

-------edit---------

Thanks for the answer! I put all generated classes under **namespace MyProjectName**

compiled it and seems it worked, I put the generated C#DLL into Mono and the editor can auto complete **MyprojectName.ClassName.Method()**.

But the compiler also complained: **EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_MaxFlowGraph**

(Before that it complained DLL not found, so I put in the original C++ dll and it stopped)

I'm using Mono under Win7 32bit, and no idea what's happening -- I'm a noob, I need help, help.

It's 22:36pm here in Australia so **MERRY CHRISTMAS** guys!

Comment: there's no way to directly notify a user outside of chat or one of their posts.

Comment: Just did it in a dirt way :P, hope Marc can see this soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new project in Visual Studio of type **Class Library**. Then right-click the project and select *Add > Existing items*.. Then select all generated `*.cs` files generated by SWIG. <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+B</kbd> and it compiles.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you go into the vcproj file created in your answer you can actually edit it to contain a single file wildcard such as "*.cs" so that it will continue to work as new files are added to the C# bindings. We use this method in a project I'm currently working on. It takes a few minutes to tweak it to your needs, but it helps with automated builds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I put all generated classes under **namespace MyProjectName** I compiled it and seems it worked, I put the generated C#DLL into Mono and the editor can auto complete **MyprojectName.ClassName.Method()**. 

But the compiler also complained:
**EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacks_MaxFlowGraph**
(Before that it complained **DLL not found**, so I put in the original C++ dll and it stopped)

I'm using Mono under Win7 32bit.

It's 22:36pm here in Australia so MERRY CHRISTMAS guys!